# Using the LinkedIn API to import companies data into a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am developing a rails application (rails 3.2), and I utilise a companies model(:name, :industry, :description, :logo etc).

I would like to use the Linked API to fetch data for specific company (I would specify the url or the company) and then it be added to my data (such as the company info, industry, logo etc).

Firstly is this possible?

Secondly if so, how does one go about doing this(step-by-step)? I have only done basic coding in rails and have so far avoid APIs.

I am aware of the linkedin gem for rails, but if it is needed in this scenario and/or required how to use it for this application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but I read this:

No LinkedIn data can be stored: The only exceptions are storing the Member ID for subsequent API calls, and storing the user's profile data when given explicit user permission by the owner of the profile using a LinkedIn-provided interface to obtain the user's consent.